# why wouldn't a record owner be able to see his own record?

Tags: force.com, security

I'm running into this problem, and I can't quite understand why this would occur.  a user created some records for a single object and the  record owner can't see his own record.

In fact it gets even more weird,  he can only see some of the records that he created for the same object.

Comment: Are you able to see all of the records? If so, I'd look at the profile level required to access the object and the VF page to edit the object's records. Also check the Org log for any changes that may have occurred which changed permissions on the objects or the profile the user is assigned to.

Comment: Have you checked that the person who created the record is still the record owner? Maybe you have a workflow rule to reassign it? Is the object a child in a Master Detail relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh, turned out a sharing rules recalc fixed it.

Comment: Good one, haven't seen that one coming :D Make sure you mark it as accepted answer when sufficient time passes!

Comment: thanks for your help Eyescream. It was really wierd, because the sharing rules were defined PRIOR to the record being written. This does involve a managed package, so that's a variable that I cannot account for.

Answer (score 3):

Creator != Owner.

You might have some workflow rules, assignment rules (on Cases & Leads only I think?) or even triggers that transfer ownership from him after creation. What you might try:

1. Add Owner field to page layout & history tracking and ask him to create new one?
2. Add "Sharing" button to the page layout and examine the results (if you don't want to add it, the link for custom objects is `https://instance.salesforce.com/p/share/CustomObjectSharingDetail?parentId={!obj.Id}`, for standard objects it varies per object I think. You can hit "Expand List" to see more detailed info.
3. There's always the old reliable debug log ;)

Bit more obscure cases - records Owned by users without Role are invisible if you don't have "View All" permission.

I think that records owned by deactivated users also behave funny (but only when you try to update them? they should be visible all right). But in order to own something you need at least Read permission in profile / perm. set (attempts to reassign data to such user fail with "TRANSFER_REQUIRES_READ" error).